# Apache Sling & Eclipse - Error while installing support bundle / starting runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, sling

when clicking on the "install" link in the Eclipse Server configuration page of Apache Sling Server Runtime to install the "support bundle", I get an **java.net.ConnectException** .

1. I'm **not** behind a proxy. Really not.
2. Can't start the sling server. Get "no repository found" & "connection refused"
3. It did work yesterday...

Best regards

**SOLUTION:**
it's EXTERNAL runtime - meaning you need to start the runtime independently from Eclipse... download the launchpad jar from the website and run it outside of eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy as that: it's **EXTERNAL** runtime - meaning you need to start the runtime *independently from Eclipse*... download the launchpad jar from the website and **run it** outside of eclipse.